# How to GRANT/REVOKE user permissions for user on Firebird 1.5?

Tags: security, firebird

I need to create a user in firebird 1.5 and give him permissions to access only some specific tables.
I have managed to create the user, but apparently GRANT/REVOKE operations only work on version 2.1 or above.
SO, how to do it?

**UPDATE**
Actually i was mistaken, GRANT and REVOKE both work fine in version 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird has had `GRANT` and `REVOKE` since its initial version. See the Interbase 6.0 Language Reference, available from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ (near the end of the page).

Eg for `GRANT`:

> ```
> GRANT <privileges> ON [TABLE] {tablename | viewname}
> ```

```
      TO {<object> | <userlist> | GROUP UNIX_group}
  | EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE procname TO {<object> | <userlist>}
  | <role_granted> TO {PUBLIC | <role_grantee_list>};
<privileges> = {ALL [PRIVILEGES] | <privilege_list>}
<privilege_list> = SELECT
  | DELETE
  | INSERT
  | UPDATE [(col [, col ...])]
  | REFERENCES [(col [, col ...])] [, <privilege_list> ...]
<object> = PROCEDURE procname
  | TRIGGER trigname
  | VIEW viewname
  | PUBLIC
  [, <object> ...]
<userlist> = [USER] username
  | rolename
  | Unix_user}
  [, <userlist> ...]
  [WITH GRANT OPTION]
<role_granted> = rolename [, rolename ...]
<role_grantee_list> = [USER] username [, [USER] username ...] [WITH ADMIN OPTION]
```

And for `REVOKE`:

> ```
> REVOKE [GRANT OPTION FOR] <privileges> ON [TABLE]
> ```

```
          {tablename | viewname}
       FROM {<object> | <userlist> | <rolelist> | GROUP UNIX_group}
   | EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE procname
       FROM {<object> | <userlist>}
   | <role_granted> FROM {PUBLIC | <role_grantee_list>}};
<privileges> = {ALL [PRIVILEGES] | <privilege_list>} <privilege_list> = {
SELECT
   | DELETE
   | INSERT
   | UPDATE [(col [, col ...])]
   | REFERENCES [(col [, col ...])] [, <privilege_list> ...]}}
<object> ={
   PROCEDURE procname
   | TRIGGER trigname
   | VIEW viewname
   | PUBLIC
   [, <object>]}
<userlist> = [USER] username [, [USER] username ...]
<rolelist> = rolename [, rolename]
<role_granted> = rolename [, rolename ...]
<role_grantee_list> = [USER] username [, [USER] username ...]
```

The Firebird documentation used to be fragmented in the original Interbase 6 documentation and a [language reference update](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25.html) which only described the changes introduced in newer versions.

However there now is a complete [Firebird 2.5 language reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html).

Comment: Regarding the documentation fragmentation: if I want to find out if a feature is present in V2.5, do I need to search the language reference update for Firebird 1.0 **and** 1.5 **and**  2.0 **and** 2.5 or is it sufficient to only look into the update for 2.5? Are the "update manuals" cumulative?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The latest language reference update (for 2.5) contains all changes since Firebird 1.0, so you only need to check the last one (+ the Interbase 6 Language Reference). It specifies what version introduced or changed a feature. There is a new full language reference coming (it is already available in Russian, but the translation to English is still in progress).

Comment: Thanks, don't know where i have read that this only works above 2.1, it works fine in 1.5, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @MateusViccari You might have looked at a 2.1 (or higher) language reference update, if you look at [grant and revoke](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-security-grant-revoke.html) you might get the impression it was only added in Firebird 2.0